# CSP blocked the loading of a resource at data:application/javascript;base64,KGZ1b... (“script-src”)

Tags: javascript, firefox, content-security-policy

We are developing a CSP and encountered a situation where a violation is reported by Firefox (v 60.0.2), but not by Chrome:

> Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at data:application/javascript;base64,KGZ1b... (“script-src”)

What is it and should we be worried? Can we address it?

Our Content-Security-Policy:

> default-src 'none'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self' data: www.google-analytics.com; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com 'report-sample'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self'; child-src 'none'; frame-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; report-uri /csp_reports; plugin-types none

Many thanks.

Comment: Seems like you need to figure out if your application code or the www.google-analytics.com code is what’s trying to use a script with that 'data:' URL. If it is, then it looks like you need to add 'data:' as a source for your script-src directive — in order for whatever is trying to use that 'data:' URL (the www.google-analytics.com 
 I guess) to work as expected (rather than not actually doing what you expect it to, which is what it would appear it happening now)

Comment: Yes it fails to fetch www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js. Couldn't find anything obvious in any javascript. Adding data: to script-src does fix it but that would open up a vulnerability that we prefer to avoid. Have googled widely but still no luck on this. It is strange that Firefox trips up on this but Chrome doesn't...

Comment: Yeah I don’t know exactly why you get that error in Firefox but not in Chrome — but it could be either that google analytics does some capability checking or UA sniffing and serves up something different to Chrome than it does to Firefox. But anyway you’re right to be wary of allowing data: URLs — allowing them is nearly as bad as specifying 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval'.